# Installing ni-visa ubuntu 16.04 - conflicts between attempted installs of nikali-2

Tags: pyvisa

I downloaded NI-VISA for Linux version 5.4.1f0, and ran the INSTALL with cmd:

```
bash INSTALL --nodeps
```

But I getting this error:

```
Installing NI-VISA for Linux version 5.4.1f0...
Pre Installation .
Post Installation .
Pre Installation ...................................
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        file /usr/local/natinst conflicts between attempted installs of nikali-2
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: You might get more answers from [Super user](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Tried with  http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-17.0/6700/en/  
10:ni-pal-nikalmod-17.0.0.49152-0+f0################################# [ 18%]
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.bglXbL: 4: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.bglXbL: /sbin/chkconfig: Permission denied
warning: %post(ni-pal-nikalmod-17.0.0.49152-0+f0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 126
11:ni-pal-17.0.0.49152-0+f0 ################################# [ 20%]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this ISO instead 
http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-17.0/6700/en/
Then its works